# Posting master's thesis on arxiv?

Tags: thesis, arxiv

I read [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/should-one-put-their-masters-thesis-online), in which all answers recommend posting one's master's thesis online. My thesis is available from my university's repository, but I'm thinking about posting it on arXiv since it's more easily searchable. However, I don't think I've seen master theses on arXiv. Is this something that people typically do? Are there disadvantages that I'm missing?

Comment: If it is worth being read by many people, why not consider turning it into a publication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting a master's thesis on the arXiv is uncommon, but not unheard of.  My feeling is that there's little point to it: if there's material worth publishing in your thesis, then you should turn it into papers and post them on the arXiv (in which case the thesis is unnecessary), and if it's not worth publishing then it's not worth posting to the arXiv.

If you decide to post both the thesis and the papers to the arXiv, you should indicate the relationship between them clearly in the comments so you don't look like you are inflating your publication record with duplicates, as well as in case you trigger the automated plagiarism detection in the arXiv.

One potential issue is coauthors.  If anything in your thesis is coauthored with someone else (either from a previous paper or to appear in a future paper), then I do not think you should post the thesis to the arXiv.  The problem is that you'd be pointing readers towards a version that lists you as the only author and relegates your coauthors to a brief note in the text, and you would be increasing the chances that they would cite the thesis rather than the coauthored papers.  Instead, it's best to emphasize the papers by posting them to the arXiv instead.

Comment: Any material in a (master or any other) thesis that has been published previously should be properly referenced. Any contribution from others should be acknowledged. Before entering common work into a thesis, the other authors should give their permission.
So none of these can be a reason **not** to submit the thesis to arXiv.

Comment: @DannyRuijters: I agree that it's not unethical to post a thesis to the arXiv that contains coauthored material, but I consider it unfriendly to the coauthors.  The thesis technically gives them credit (since they are cited within it), but in a way that is less visible to most readers and not visible at all if the thesis is cited.  Posting the thesis disadvantages the coauthors compared with posting the papers themselves, and I see no advantages that can outweigh this issue.

Comment: I do not agree with this "if it's not published but in a thesis, then nobody cares about it" attitude. (1) Theses are something we (still!) have to write and (2) there are plenty of introductory notes online which combine many papers into one coherent piece of information that are not only helpful, but have made their authors well-known and respected in the community. Why not combine these two things into one?

Comment: What about a "reading project" type of masters thesis? In that case, "if there's material worth publishing in your thesis, then you should turn it into papers" wouldn't be appropriate. In that case is it advisable to put it on the arXiv (solely for easy sharing with others/some prestige for young PhD students trying to impress potential advisors)?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this something that people typically do? Are there disadvantages that I'm missing?

There are **NO** disadvantages, but IMHO, this is not something that people typically do.

At least in my field, CS, nobody care about PhD theses, let alone Master theses. Because if there are any contributions in the theses, they should be published in conferences. That's the version that people want to read.

Comment: In my experience, the people who care about MSc or PhD thesis are the ones trying to replicate something, whether a lab result or an algorithm. So it sounds strange to me that no-one in CS cares about theses. Don't you replicate stuff? :)

Comment: @semi-extrinsic: very often, PhD theses are just long summaries of published papers as the majority of professors (I am talking only about CS) expect you to produce publications during your thesis. That's different to other tracks where you can get your PhD without any publications. So all replication will usually be done using your published conference/journal papers.