# Posting a (non-original research) Masters thesis on arXiv?

Tags: publications, thesis, masters, arxiv, online-publication

Based on the following posts:

[Posting master's thesis on arxiv?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58943/posting-masters-thesis-on-arxiv)

[Should one put their Master's thesis online?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/should-one-put-their-masters-thesis-online)

although my question differs in that my "Master's thesis" was not part of a formal Masters program. Rather it is more of an extensive reading project that I did over the last 10 months under a very well-known advisor in my field through the Fulbright Scholarship. I've a 150+ page review on a topic I think would be of interested to others in my field at my level of knowledge. However it does not contain anything new, and I think this means it has no place on the arXiv. It solely summarizes the inception of a topic from the 1960s, and summarizes a new take on the topic that my adviser uncovered in some seminal work around 2010.

Can I get some input on the pros and cons of posting it on the arxiv/ [inspireHEP](https://inspirehep.net/authors/983328) profile?

Pros:

- easy to send to friends, peers, potential collaborators, and most importantly, potential PhD advisors at my uni

Cons:

- it might look petty/immature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my field (cosmology), plenty of researchers and professors post lecture notes on arXiv, and of course many people write and publish review articles which don't contain any new results. So there's no requirement of novelty to post on arXiv.

Whether it looks immature largely depends on the quality of your writing. A poorly written review will not be read, and could reflect badly on you if you continue in academia (employers and grant reviewers will look at your Inspire and/or ADS profile). Bear in mind that you can't remove things from arXiv.

I would highly recommend asking your supervisor about this. They are best placed to tell you whether it's appropriate or not, according to the quality of your work and the conventions in your field. If you don't post on arXiv, you could consider uploading the pdf to your own website, a public github repository, google drive or similar. Then you can still share the link with interested people.

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph is precisely my worry. I am quite proud of the quality of the work, but someone else may not be and that could effect postdoc opportunities. I think your website idea is a happy medium! Cheers :)

Comment: @LopeyTall it's what I did with my own Master's thesis and it's done me no harm so far :) good luck with your PhD!

Comment: Thank you! and thank you for passing some wisdom down as you pursue yours!

Answer (score -1):

Putting it online usually cannot hurt, but do not expect many people to read it. I would only recommend against putting it online when you know larger flaws.
Minor flaws should be not big problem, because people know that a masters thesis is one of your first works and probably not perfect. And they probably know that their own master thesis is less important than their recent works as well.

You write

> However it **does not contain anything new**, and I think this means it has no place on the arXiv. It solely summarizes the inception of a topic from the 1960s, and **summarizes a new take on the topic that my adviser uncovered** in some seminal work around 2010.

Reading this, I would think you and your advisor actually did write about something new. Maybe not a major breakthrough, but you're thinking about putting it on arXiv and not about submitting it to nature.

It reads a bit like you are thinking the actual work could be the work of your advisor. But when it was his idea and your work to actually work on it, verify it and write it down, you still would be the main contributor and the first author on a paper.

Having a great idea justifies being an author (often the last author), but the actual work was delegated to you and the quality of the work was good enough to earn you a masters degree.

So I do not think you have anything to lose. But I am not sure if you will gain much, so I would just do what I am feeling what's right. Given your question, you seem to like to upload it, but when you are doubting it too much you do not have to.

Comment: I understood it so that the advisor did some work in 2010 that this thesis summarizes. I did not take it so that the work in 2010 was done, even partially, by the author of the present thesis.

Comment: I assume some work was done, when someone got a masters degree. The question here is the novelty of the work, which depends on what parts of the idea the supervisor published or what someone else published in the meantime.

Comment: @Tommi indeed! This present review is solely that - a review of a certain procedure in the field established circa 19060's (although updated to the more approachable methodology of current literature) as well as a recap of its new application in my advisers work from 2010. I was not involved whatsoever in this 2010 work.